# Python3.5 subprocess error

Tags: python, logging, subprocess, python-3.5

I am using below function to read my python scripts output line by line and save in parallel. But getting Traceback error in end.

**Code:**

```
def myrun(cmd):
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    stdout = []
    while True:
        line = p.stdout.readline()
        stdout.append(line)
        print (line),
        if line == '' and p.poll() != None:
            break
    return ''.join(stdout)
```

When call function as :

```
myrun(os.system("./tests_run.py"))
```

I get below error:

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./Portability_Tests.py", line 38, in <module>
    myrun(os.system("./tests_run.py"))
  File "./Tests.py", line 11, in myrun
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 676, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1171, in _execute_child
    args = list(args)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Anyone know how can i fix this error ?

Comment: You don't need to wrap the command with `os.system` (which is insecure BTW);  try `myrun("./tests_run.py")` (assuming the command is correct).

Comment: I did try same but doesnt help and throwing syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) function receives a "sequence of program arguments or else a single string" as its `args` argument.

What you are passing in the `args` argument is the output of the `os.system()` call which according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) is the "exit status of the process", thus an `int` number. Instead in the `cmd` variable you should directly pass the string (or an other iterator) of your file `/tests_run.py`. If you want this path to be relative to your current project you can use the [os.path](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) module.

Comment: I did try directly calling "./tests_run.py" but thtows syntax error.

Comment: Can you please post the traceback?

Comment: no traceback it keeps printing b'' until i manually do the keyboard interrupt 
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tests_run.py", line 52, in <module>
    myrun("./Tests.py")
  File "./tests_run.py", line 16, in myrun
    print (line),
KeyboardInterrupt

Comment: That error has nothing to do with the original error of the question. You keep seeing this b" because you have the  while True statement in your code. You need to modify that so that the script can stop at some point. However as far as this thread is concerned, since you managed to access the ./tests.py file you can accept an answer and close it.